pyinstaller + pyside6 problem: dlopen Shiboken.abi3.so: Symbol not found
I have an app based on PySide6, with the macOS binary created with pyinstaller.
I'm experiencing a strange problem when running the built application - sometimes the build is fine and the app starts without any problems.
But then I change some not important lines of code, rebuild the app - and the build is broke.
When I execute the binary, I get the following message:
PySide6/__init__.py: Unable to import Shiboken from /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/base_library.zip, /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/lib-dynload, /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks
PySide6/__init__.py: Unable to import Shiboken from /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/base_library.zip, /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/lib-dynload, /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "gui.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "PySide6/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
  File "PySide6/__init__.py", line 64, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "shiboken6/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN8Shiboken14BindingManager14dumpWrapperMapEv
  Referenced from: <B31AD3C0-E93A-3A53-BC28-ABA64B3F119C> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so
  Expected in:     <3D177653-B9D2-3FF2-A8CB-A4BBADC6B7B6> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib
[51645] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: dlopen(/Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN8Shiboken14BindingManager14dumpWrapperMapEv
  Referenced from: <B31AD3C0-E93A-3A53-BC28-ABA64B3F119C> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so
  Expected in:     <3D177653-B9D2-3FF2-A8CB-A4BBADC6B7B6> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib
[51645] Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "gui.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "PySide6/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
  File "PySide6/__init__.py", line 64, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "shiboken6/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN8Shiboken14BindingManager14dumpWrapperMapEv
  Referenced from: <B31AD3C0-E93A-3A53-BC28-ABA64B3F119C> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/shiboken6/Shiboken.abi3.so
  Expected in:     <3D177653-B9D2-3FF2-A8CB-A4BBADC6B7B6> /Users/rafal/Developer/family-rules-client/dist/Family Rules.app/Contents/Frameworks/libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib

Some additional information:

I'm using python 3.12.4, installed using pyenv, although the same issue occurred also on 3.10.6
I'm using a fresh venv, with only three packages installed: PySide6, pyinstaller, requests (without version specified == newest)
my spec file is the following:

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['src/main.py'],
    pathex=['src/'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ('src/resources', 'resources')
    ],
    hiddenimports=['shiboken6'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='Family Rules',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='Family Rules',
)
app = BUNDLE(
    coll,
    name='Family Rules.app',
    icon='src/resources/icon.icns',
    bundle_identifier=None,
    info_plist={
            'LSUIElement': True,
            'LSBackgroundOnly': False,
            'NSUIElement': True
        }
)


"some not important lines of code": it seems clear that those lines are probably important to some level. Also, compilers often base their contents with cached files and data. I've never used pyinstaller, but you should check your project/build tree for some "build" data/directories and eventually consider deleting them (after proper backup).

"some not important lines of code" - for example removing unused imports. For me it's clear that pyinstaller is randomly unable to collect all dependencies, I'm struggling with making it work all the time
